# Replace each instance of multiple values in a vector with a value specific for the unique value

Tags: r

I have vector

```
a <- c(2, 1, 1, 2)
```

and I want to replace each unique value with another unique value. For instance, I want 2 -> 'a' and 1 -> 'b' to create a vector with the same order like this:

```
c <- c('a', 'b', 'b', 'a')
```

I tried something this, but it didn't work:

```
replace(a, a %in% unique(a), b)
```

I want to avoid manually going to all unique values to generalize in case a is large. The replacement strings are just examples. The solution should also generalize to completely different strings
 or values.  E.g.: 2 -> 'Walter' and 1 -> 'Getrude'.

Comment: Try `letters[a]`

Comment: It's just an example, I want this to work for any string. I'll add this.

Comment: Yup...good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to proceed here would be to define two data frames, one for the starting values and the other for the values to be mapped:

```
library(plyr)

df1 <- data.frame(a=c(2, 1, 1, 2))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1, 2), value=c('a', 'b'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

result <- join(df1, df2)$value
result

[1] "b" "a" "a" "b"
```

Having a dedicated data frame or table for mapping the values is probably a good long term strategy.

Comment: The result should be [1] "b" "a" "a" "b" because the order is important has to be preserved.

Comment: @JAQuent I updated my answer to use `join` from the `plyr` package.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match` to get a numeric index and then replace based on it (using `base R`)

```
c('a', 'b')[match(a, unique(a))]
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "a"
```